# How to work around inability to use lenses with existential types?

Tags: haskell, existential-type, lenses, haskell-lens

I am using Edward Kmett's **lens** library for the first time, and finding it rather nice, but I ran into a snag...

The question at [1] explains that existential quantifiers disrupt makeLenses.  I really rather want to use an existential with lenses in some fashion.

As background, I have the class:

```
class (TextShow file, Eq file, Ord file, Typeable file) => File file where
  fromAnyFile :: AnyFile -> Maybe file
  fileType :: Simple Lens file FileType
  path :: Simple Lens file Text.Text
  provenance :: Simple Lens file Provenance
```

For the actual question, I want to have the type:

```
data AnyFile = forall file . File file => AnyFile { _anyFileAnyFile :: File }
```

And I want to be able to write something along the lines of:

```
instance File AnyFile where
  fromAnyFile (AnyFile file) = cast file
  fileType (AnyFile file) = fileType . anyFile
  path (AnyFile file) = path . anyFile
  provenance (AnyFile file) = provenance . anyFile
```

This doesn't work, for the reason explained in [1].  If I ask GHC for debugging information by compiling with `-ddump-splices`, I get:

```
Haskell/Main.hs:1:1: Splicing declarations
    makeLenses ''AnyFile ======> Haskell/Main.hs:59:1-20
```

The splice itself is blank, which indicates to me that no declarations are produced by it.  This part I expect and understand now that I have read [1].

What I would like to know is how I can do this - what might I do to work around the problem?  What might I do to avoid swimming upstream on this?  I would like to be able to access any part of my structures through a path of composed lenses, but because I have fields in other types with types such as `Set AnyFile`, I cannot do so unless I can access the content of `AnyFile` with a lens.

[1] [Existential quantifier silently disrupts Template Haskell (makeLenses). Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256091/existential-quantifier-silently-disrupts-template-haskell-makelenses-why)

Comment: Just for anybody wondering, what I did was to use the suggestion below; the definition needed to be `lens (\(AnyFile file) -> file) (\_ value -> AnyFile value)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the worst case, you can always implement the lenses yourself without relying on Template Haskell at all.

For example, given a getter and a setter function for your type, you can create a lens using the [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-Lens.html#g:3) function:

```
 lens :: (s -> a) -> (s -> b -> t) -> Lens s t a b
```

I believe this may not be the most performant option, but it's certainly the easiest.

I don't know how to do this for your case (or with existential types in general), but here's a trivial example using a record:

```
data Foo = Foo { _field :: Int }
foo = lens _field (\ foo new -> foo { _field = new })
```

Hopefully this illustrates the idea well enough to apply to your code.

Comment: Hmm...  I did not know about the lens function.  Thank you!  The docs are rather, er, large. :)  I'm trying to make something work now, and will accept the answer if it does. :)

Comment: The type of lens, at least in my version, appears to be `Functor f => (s -> a) -> (s -> b -> t) -> (a -> f b) -> s -> f t`.  Okay.  Looks like some sort of continuation-passing thing, I can probably figure it out...

Comment: Oh I see.  Right.  I only need the first two parameters because the remaining ones are part of the lens itself...  Maybe the docs can explain what the `s` is to me.

Comment: Your example helped and I got it working!  Yay!  Sorry for all the comments, if that spammed you; I am new to Stack Overflow as you can see. :)

Comment: @IreneKnapp: Don't worry about it. I'm glad you got it working.